# Cakephp beforeFilter vs constructor

Tags: php, cakephp

I am new to cakephp. I found a largely used method

```
beforeFilter()
```

My question is, how it's differ from a class constructor? 
What if i called

```
parent::beforeFilter();
```

from constructor instead of beforeFilter();
I just want to know what if i write the same code in

```
public function __construct() {
   // Code here
}
```

instead of

```
public function beforeFilter() {
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

construct() is for construction, to load things you need.

> __construct( ) public
>   Constructor
>
> Parameters:
>   ComponentCollection $collection
>   A ComponentCollection this component can use to lazy load its components

http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-Component.html#___construct

---

beforeFilter() executes functions that you NEED to be executed before any other action

> Controller::beforeFilter()
>   This function is executed before every action in the controller. It’s a handy place to check for an active session or inspect user permissions.

http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-Controller.html#_beforeFilter

> Called before the controller action. You can use this method to configure and customize components or perform logic that needs to happen before each controller action.
>
> Note:
>   The beforeFilter() method will be called for missing actions, and scaffolded actions.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#request-life-cycle-callbacks

Usually you will not need a constructor as, when following CakePHP conventions there are only very few scenarios where you actually have no other option than to "force" loading something manually...

Comment: I disagree about the permissions, that's what the isAuthorized() callback is thought for.

Comment: @burzum Are you saying that you disagree with the official CakePHP documentation? They say that "it is a handy place to check for an active session or inspect user permissions." You can check permissions from the beforeFilted() method and based on that, determine what you want to show in the view, correct? I am not sure if we are talking about the same thing or if you are referring to something else.

Comment: Yes, I do so. This sentence is a little misleading and should point to the Auth component and it's isAuthorized() callback. Or give a better advice on where and how to implement authorization checks. However, this is an old version and I'm to lazy to update the docs. I've rewritten Authentication (https://github.com/cakephp/authentication) for Cake3 which will make it into the next release and I'm in the planing phase of the Authorization layer for a later 3.x release or 4.0, which is going to feature much better abstraction and a policy based implementation. Ideas are welcome.

Comment: Interesting. It is true that the documentation at https://book.cakephp.org/1.2/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Controllers.html, where it says that "beforeFilter() is a handy place to check for an active session or inspect user permissions" is the documentation of an old release. But if you go to https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html, it says exactly the same thing, and the documentation is supposed to be newer because it is for CakePHP 3.0. So maybe that is misleading too.

Answer (score 6):

Just read the description of the method in the Controller class:

> Called before the controller action. You can use this method to
>   configure and customize components or perform logic that needs to
>   happen before each controller action.

BeforeFilter is called by the Dispatcher when a URL is accessed and an action of a controller is triggered:

1. Constructor
2. BeforeFilter
3. Action
4. BeforeRender
5. AfterFilter

There is rarely a case (at least I can't remember) in which I had to do something in the constructor. Also this is a good architectural design. The constructor just initializes things and the beforeFilter allows you to configure (mostly components for example) what was initialized before.

Answer (score 1):

You can find some relevant definitions from the official CakePHP documentation at https://book.cakephp.org/1.2/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Controllers.html#the-app-controller:

> "Callbacks: CakePHP controllers come fitted with callbacks you can use to insert logic just before or after controller actions are rendered. beforeFilter(): This function is executed before every action in the controller. It’s a handy place to check for an active session or inspect user permissions."